# Why does my report recalculate totals when I scroll in Access '07?

Tags: scroll, report, ms-access-2007

Whenever I make a report in Access '07 and include some sort of total (whether counting or summing values), when I'm viewing the preview and scroll, the total recalculate.  This is really annoying as Access  takes a while (several tenths of a second) to do this, and while it does that the totals go blank.  I've looked for a solution online, but I can't find this issue described anywhere.

How can I stop the totals from recalculating when I scroll?  I'm hoping for a simple solution that would solve this for all reports, or perhaps a simple property tweak on each report.  I don't want to have to add code for every single report!

I should describe the report layouts I'm using - they contain rows of data all on one page, and at times I group the rows.  The number of rows isn't huge, maybe around 50 or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though the recordsource of your report is bound to a query, therefore this will be the default behaviour of the Access database. If this is a problem then you can always try running your query as a "Make Table" first in order to create a static table of information, and then set the reports recordsource to this.

Edit:

Alternatively, you could seek to optimise the performance of the database in an attempt to make the recalculation un-noticeable. First place to look would be the query itself (especially if it has been built with the query designer), then possibly looking at the location of the file, is it on a network server, or local? If local then significant performance increases can be achieved with use of a SSD.

Comment: Well you're right, that did work, but I don't like two aspects of this: 1) I have to have an extra table for each query and 2) I would have to command the query to run each time before a user views the report.  I'm really surprised there's not an option in the report of "don't recalculate".  I'll have to look into this more before I settle with your answer.  I guess if I had to choose between this and VBA code, I'd probably go with VBA as long as it's fairly concise.

Comment: @andrewb I appreciate it's not ideal, I have added some other suggestions to my answer which attack the problem from a different angle

Comment: Ah don't get me started on SSDs. We have an office of around 30 people, and our server uses a spinning platter... we only have like 100 GB of data, it's crazy. Anyway the file is stored on the server, so yeah. If I did do the make table query, would it cope if someone ran the query with different filters while someone was already viewing the report? Oh I suppose the table would just be made on the local machine right?

Comment: @andrewb That depends on whether each user has there own local copy of the front-end, or whether they are all sharing one network front-end. If local then you should be all good, if not then I suggest capturing the users name as part of the table name to ensure they don't clash.

Comment: Oh yeah everyone has their own local front end. Doing otherwise is bad practice from my understanding. Anyway looks like you've given the best answer even though it's not quite what I was hoping for, so I'll give you the check. Thanks for the help.